# scipy.signal.fftconvolve behavior has changed (comparing 1.1 onward with 0.19.1)

Tags: python, scipy, convolution

I was trying to understand and port an old code written for python 2.7 in 3.7. I found that in python 3.7/3.8 my code was detecting less features and after spending some time I realized that scipy.signal.fftconvolve is what is causing it to change.

AFAIK convolution should have not changed at all (also documentation does not reflect any such changes). How can I understand why I am getting different values. Here is the code which illustrate the change:

I create a simple 2-d gaussian image (13x13) (called it g) and then convolved it with a simple 9x9 image which has all values zero except two which have value 1 and -1. (This should give me edge detection as done by gabor filter at a specific angle defined by x and y parameters). Final convolution is stored in variable c (has dimension 9x9 as I used 'same').

I first run the code with venv running python 2.7 where scipy version is 0.19.1. There I save g and c to disk.

Then I run it in python 3.7 (with scipy 1.6.0). Here however after g and c are created, I read the values of g and c as saved by python 2.7 code and compare how much the values have changed. Apparently there is non-negligible change. Change is more pronounced when edge detection is not in horizontal/vertical direction. This suggests difference in precision of how sin and cosine are being calculated, but change seems too large for that.

Also, is this the right place to ask this Q?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter
from scipy.signal import fftconvolve

#This function 2 b used in python 3.7
def load_and_compare(np_3, np_2_fPath):
    np_2 = np.load(np_2_fPath)
    v = (np_3==np_2).all()
    if not v:
        print(np.sum(np.abs(np_3 - np_2)))
    return v

size = 13
alt = np.zeros((int(size), int(size)), np.float64)
alt[int(size // 2), int(size // 2)] = 1
g = gaussian_filter(alt, 2*np.sqrt(2.), mode='constant')
g[g < 0.05 * g.max()] = 0

#Comment it while running for python 3.7
np.save("g", g)    

#Comment it while running for python 2.7
print(load_and_compare(g, "g.npy")) 

size = 9
acts = np.zeros((size, size), np.float64)
x = 3.695518130045147
y = 1.5307337294603591
acts[int(size / 2 + y), int(size / 2 + x)] = 1.
acts[int(size / 2 - y), int(size / 2 - x)] = -1.
c = fftconvolve(acts, g, mode='same')

#Comment it while running for python 3.7
np.save("c", c)    

#Comment it while running for python 2.7
print(load_and_compare(c, "c.npy"))
```

In python 3.7 difference in g is printed as: 2.42861286636753e-16 (this is negligible)

difference in c (convolution) however is: 0.18917080177322904 (this is not right)

As I increase the size of c from 9 to a higher value, I get more difference.